# Adminer Login PHP

Tags: php, post, authentication, adminer

I'm manage user logins into Adminer. The PHP code to try to achieve this is below:

```
<?php
function adminer_object() {

class AdminerSoftware extends Adminer {

    function name() {
      // custom name in title and heading
      return  "<a href='localhost'>My App</a> Admin";;
    }

    function credentials() {
      $DB_USER=$_POST['auth[username]'];
      $DB_PASSWORD=$_POST['auth[password]'];

      // server, username and password for connecting to database
      return array('localhost', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    }
  }

  return new AdminerSoftware;
}
include "./adminer-4.2.3.php";
```

When I click the login button, I'm taken to the regular page that lists databases but only datatbases which allow guest access are listed. The only way I am able to log in is to replace the return array with hard coded creds.

```
      return array('localhost', 'user', 'password');
```

When using this, whether I enter no creds or the 'user' and 'password' values, hitting the login button takes me to a full list of databases.

I suspect there's something very simple which I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: `$_POST['auth[username]']` isn't valid PHP syntax

Comment: I have tried various permutations of $_POST[ ... ];

Comment: var_dump($_POST) to see what's in it

Comment: function credentials() {
      //$DB_USER=$_POST['auth[username]'];
      //$DB_PASSWORD=$_POST['auth[password]'];

      // server, username and password for connecting to database
      //return array('localhost', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
      return array('localhost',/*, $_GET["username"], get_password()*/'username', 'password');
       var_dump($_POST)
}

This causes the page not to load.

Comment: Never mind, that was the missing semi-colon.
Still can't see the value of $_POST thought...

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delayed response.  I am trying to use post.  Adminer is a Database Webadmin in some terms comparable to PHPMyAdmin and SQLBuddy.  Unlike these others, it seems like I have to hard code the login credentials.  The login form is provided by Adminer.

Comment: To see how the form is made goto: https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/v4.2.3/adminer/include/adminer.inc.php#L87

Answer (score 0):

Try change credentials() function like this:

```
function credentials() {
    $DB_USER=$_POST['auth']['username'];
    $DB_PASSWORD=$_POST['auth']['password'];

    // server, username and password for connecting to database
    return array('localhost', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I no-longer have access to that database or server.  So I can't test this, sorry.